# 'gem install -v' installs wrong version of a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'd like to install bundler v1.2.3 on my machine.
First, I checked out the remote gem repo whether that version of the gem exists:

```
$ gem list --remote | grep "^bundler "
bundler (1.2.3)
```

Then I tried to install the gem, but a different version(v1.1.5):

```
$ sudo gem install bundler -v '1.2.3'
Successfully installed bundler-1.1.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.1.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.1.5...
```

Why is this happening and is there any solution for this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: That's very strange. Try putting `-v '1.2.3'` before `bundler`.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested on my Mac running 10.8, worked no problem. I had Bundler 1.3.5 already installed.

```
andys-MacBook-Pro:.gem uw$ gem list 'bundler'

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.3.5)
andys-MacBook-Pro:.gem uw$ gem install 'bundler' -v '1.2.3'
Fetching: bundler-1.2.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.2.3
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.2.3
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.2.3
1 gem installed
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the gem (bundler 1.2.3) installed properly in my Win 7 32 bit machine. give a try again

```
C:\Windows\System32>gem install bundler -v 1.2.3
Fetching: bundler-1.2.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.2.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.2.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.2.3...
```

Comment: I'm using Mac, and what I did was just the same. Thanks.

Comment: Aaah!! okay, itz really wierd. i have installed bundler(latest and even required versions when needed) many times on my windows machine and faced no problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

When I used `gem install bundler '1.2.3'`
I got the following.

```
PS C:\Users\....> gem install bundler '1.2.3'
Fetching: bundler-1.2.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.2.3
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '1.2.3' (>= 0) in any repository
```

But it worked fine when I remove the quotation marks and just used 

`gem install bundler 1.2.3`

EDIT ~ Didn't see the comment to the previous answer. Looks like this question is already solved.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you use sudo to do the install but not to do the list. This can sometimes cause a problem, especially if you have multiple versions of ruby/gem installed (or if you use rvm).

I've also seen oddities like this if one of the gems is not using rubygems.org as the default gemserver. What does `$ sudo gem list --remote | grep "^bundler "` give you?

It may not matter but what version of ruby are you using?